# Most efficient way to pack boxes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

So say your running an eCommerce site, and are writing a function to take an array of an order and pack it into boxes.

For example say you have a collection of all the products of the order:

```
   [{ product: "c5b3eb47", weight: 1},
    { product: "c5b3eb47", weight: 1},
    { product: "c5b3eb47", weight: 1},
    { product: "c5b3eb47", weight: 1},
    { product: "c5b3eb47", weight: 1},
    { product: "2e5e38b0", weight: 2},
    { product: "2e5e38b0", weight: 2},
    { product: "4939730d", weight: 4}]
```

and we want to pack this into the minimum number of boxes of weight 5. (There are no products that weight more then 5). What would be the most efficient method to accomplish this?

An example output would be

```
   [
    [{
        product: "c5b3eb47",
        weight: 1
    }, {
        product: "4939730d",
        weight: 4
    }],
    [{
        product: "c5b3eb47",
        weight: 1
    }, {
        product: "c5b3eb47",
        weight: 1
    }, {
        product: "c5b3eb47",
        weight: 1
    }],
    [{
        product: "c5b3eb47",
        weight: 1
    }, {
        product: "2e5e38b0",
        weight: 2
    }, {
        product: "2e5e38b0",
        weight: 2
    }]
   ]
```

where three boxes where created. So far I've tried sorting heaviest first and attempting to pair with the lightest. Any help our guidance would be amazing.

Comment: Bin packing can be a complex topic and has a wide scope. You would have to look at different bin packing algorithms to find one that suits your scenario (as to which is best, which is considered off-topic here).

Comment: You're trying to solve the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which is NP-complete. This question is too broad for stack overflow. If you ever find a working algorithm for your case, you could ask for a review on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of packages! (now that I know what to search for)
Here is a 1D bin packer library. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bin-packer